# Avoid children to interfer with the parents hover. (or how to .stop(false,true) a css transition)

Tags: css

When i animate things with jQuery `.animate()`. I always take care to use `.stop(false,true)` to avoid strange animation behaviors.

In this case i wanted to make a navigation appear on the hover of certain sections. Here is a demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/meo/Kbeg8/

Now if you slowly **hover-out** the gray element on the top, you will get a infinite animation loop, since the element that fly's in is a children of the element that triggers the animation.

Since its not the first time i encounter this difficulty: Is there any pure CSS way to avoid this? (Like children's don't trigger the parents transition) If now, how would you solve it with JS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is a pure CSS3 way to do this. The property you need is [`pointer-events`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/css/pointer-events)

Adding

```
nav ul {
    pointer-events:none;
}
nav:hover ul {
    pointer-events:auto;
}
```

seems to fix it for me in Chrome 14.

Comment: wow thank you. tested it, but i think it should be the opposite auto on the ul and none on the hover. it worked in FF4 also

Comment: Since the `<ul>` is firing events, it should have `pointer-events:none` when _not_ hovered. Swapping them causes the same problem as you currently have with the other side-effect of stopping `pointer-events` on the anchor tags (making the "nav" unusable). I think the order in the answer is correct, but please let me know if it's not working :-)

Comment: Happy to help and I forgot to say I really like your code. It's a great demo :-)